# Transistor characteristics

Tags: transistors

Consider a common base biased configuration.in the input characteristics curve,as we increase the value of Vcb,input current value increases.  Hence input current increases with increase in output applied voltage.

Then how is output characteristics a straight line as Vcb increases?

As we increase Vcb input current Ie increases and as Ie is approximately equal to Ic.

Ic should increase with increase in Vcb?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing down the *formula* for \$I_C(V_{CB})\$? It's relatively easy, and finding the derivative instantly demonstrates why the curves flatten.

Answer (score 0):

When Vcb increases input current value (Ib) remains constant.

**Collector current is only controlled by Vbe** when Vce >> Vce(sat). But as a Common Base config.,  Vb is shared i.e."common to e and c" and thus Vbe is controlled here by stepping constant emitter current , Ie in the graph and sweeping Vcb.

The graph shows steps of Ic=Ie in 1mA increments .